# How to solve the problem with the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

The program should output the results executed in the user's console and send the result to me by mail. Commands from the console work fine, except for "ipconfig".

Code that works correctly:

```
import subprocess, time, os, smtplib, re
from subprocess import check_output

serverIP = "iperf.net.ru"
def startShell(serverIP):
    """Start windows command line, measuring Internet channel"""
    print("Measuring external channel, please wait...")
    try:
        information = check_output("iperf3 -c %s -i 11" % serverIP, shell = True).decode()
        return information
    except:
        print("There was an error connecting to the server!")
```

The code in which the error occurs:

```
def netSettings():
    """Show network settings"""
    try:
        netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True).decode()
        return netSet
    except:
        print("An error occurred while displaying the settings!")
```

Error Type:

```
>>> netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True).decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True).decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Output without decode function ()

```
>>> netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True)
>>> print(netSet)
b'\r\n\x8d\xa0\xe1\xe2\xe0\xae\xa9\xaa\xa0 \xaf\xe0\xae\xe2\xae\xaa\xae\xab\xa0 IP
```

Really looking forward to your advice! Honestly searched the forum before asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell used to capture the output is using a Russian OEM encoding of `cp866`, so you're probably using a Russian-localized version of Windows:

```
b = b'\r\n\x8d\xa0\xe1\xe2\xe0\xae\xa9\xaa\xa0 \xaf\xe0\xae\xe2\xae\xaa\xae\xab\xa0 IP'
print(b.decode('cp866'))
```

Output:

```
Настройка протокола IP
```

You could parse the output of `chcp` before `ipconfig` to get the code page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And there is! This line solved my problem !!! netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True).decode(encoding="866")

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the return of check_output isn't encoded using utf-8. Here's a list of standard encodings that you can try putting into `decode`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html

Answer (score -1):

```
netSet = check_output("ipconfig", shell = True).decode(encoding="866")
```

Mark Tolonen helped me solve the problem!